# ParseQuery.or() not working as expected

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a code given below

```
    ParseQuery<Request> followingsCompositeParseQuery = getFollowingsCompositeQuery();

    ParseQuery<Photo> followingsFromUserParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseModelNames.PHOTO );
    followingsFromUserParseQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery( Photo.USER_NAME, Request.FROM_USER, followingsCompositeParseQuery );

    ParseQuery<Photo> followingsToUserParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery( ParseModelNames.PHOTO );
    followingsToUserParseQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery( Photo.USER_NAME, Request.TO_USER, followingsCompositeParseQuery );

    ParseQuery<Photo> finalQuery = ParseQuery.or( Arrays.asList( followingsToUserParseQuery , followingsFromUserParseQuery));

    finalQuery.orderByDescending( "updatedAt" );
    finalQuery.findInBackground(findCallback);
```

What I found out that only one of above queries (followingsToUserParseQuery and followingsFromUserParseQuery) is executed and the one that I write first in ParseQuery.or(...) function is the one that is executed. I don't know why because I want to execute both queries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might come from how you are setting your list into the `or` method, since your question indicates that the queries individually work.

Try using this set of lines instead of the ones you currently have:

```
ParseQuery<Photo>[] photoQueries = {followingsFromUserParseQuery, followingsToUserParseQuery};
ParseQuery<Photo> finalQuery = ParseQuery.or(Arrays.asList(photoQueries));
```

The `asList()` method  returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. In this way, you're creating an array and returning a list.

Comment: That's not the problem because if I add any other query along with two queries mentioned in question code to `asList` method it is executed. Problem is just with `followingsFromUserParseQuery` and `followingsToUserParseQuery` when they are executed together.